# Regex to select words with spaces for subsititution

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have string in JS which where I need to add `'` to the values.
Example: `task: task one, client: Mr jhon` will be converted to
`task:'task one', client: 'Mr Jhon'`

Think of these string as user entered search query. This is then sent to the backed for the searching. The values need to be enclosed in `'`

Complexities

- `taskname: one two three, client: Mr Jhon` there can be more than 2 words
- `taskname: one     two, client: Mr Jhon` more than 1 space
- `taskname:one,client: Mr Jhon` can be singe word without space
- `priority:1,groupname: Mr Singh` the name of can be anything
- `priority:1,task: Mr Singh,planet:pluto,done:Yes` There can be more than 2 data points

I am using below code to convert in the string in Javascript.

```js
let myStr = `taskname: task one`
myStr = `${myStr},`
const finalStr = myStr.replace(/:((?:\w*\s*)+),/g, `:'$1',`)
console.log(finalStr)
```

Question 1: Is the regex performant?

PS: I will be using this in Node JS server.

Comment: What's the purpose of `(?:` in regex

Comment: @PankajKumar, it's `Non-capturing group`

Comment: Yeah, I misspoke. Seems like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) nonetheless. It seems like you're trying to build a JSON-like key-value pair structure here and a bit more context of where this data came from would let you do it in a more proper way than what you're attempting here. If your only question is whether the regex is performant, that's up to you to decide. If it's efficient enough for your use case, then yes, otherwise no. See [performance rant](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).

Comment: @ggorlen, thanks. Have added explanation. Yes, it is similar to JSON.

Comment: What about user input like `O'Neill` (apostroph) and `Bond, James Bond` (comma) and `Wednesday, 08:00 o'clock` (colon)? Never underestimate a user! Also `Mr Singh` without dot is an improper abbreviation, while `Pluto` is a name (upcase), not a noun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this would work for you

```js
let myStr = `taskname: task  one, client: Mr jhon
taskname: one two three, client: Mr Jhon there can be more than 2 words
taskname: one     two, client: Mr Jhon more than 1 space
taskname:one,client: Mr Jhon can be singe word without space
priority:1,groupname: Mr Singh the name of can be anything
priority:1,task: Mr Singh,planet:pluto,done:Yes There can be more than 2 data points`;

const finalStr = myStr.replace(
  /((?<=^\w+\:)(.*?)(?=\,)|(?<=\w+\:)(.*?)(?=\,)|(?<=\w+\:)(.*?)$)/gim,
  (match) => `'${match.trim()}'`
);

console.log(finalStr);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work fine:

```js
let myStr = `taskname: one two three, client: Mr Jhon
taskname: one     two, client: Mr Jhon
taskname:one,client: Mr Jhon
priority:1,groupname: Mr Singh
priority:1,task: Mr Singh,planet:pluto,done:Yes`;

const finalStr = myStr.replace(/([^,:\n]+):\s*([^,:\n]+)/g, `$1:'$2'`)
console.log(finalStr)
```

**Output**:

```
taskname:'one two three', client:'Mr Jhon'
taskname:'one     two', client:'Mr Jhon'
taskname:'one',client:'Mr Jhon'
priority:'1',groupname:'Mr Singh'
priority:'1',task:'Mr Singh',planet:'pluto',done:'Yes'
```